# Why do I need an exclamation point at the beginning of a condition?

Tags: javascript, parsehub

I'm using ParseHub to get links in a conditional manner. I can only extract the URL using a condition in this format, and I'm wondering why I need the exclamation point at the front?

```
!toLowerCase($e.text).includes("conditional")
```

Comment: That is a NOT.  It reverses your result.  You read it as "NOT To Lower Case."  So if toLowerCase returns true, the NOT reverses that to FALSE.

Comment: includes return true or false, above statement says  not includes "conditional"

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation point negates the expression. You're saying with this line of code that "if the text does **not** include the string `'conditional'`, do something..."

An easy way to demonstrate this is with this line of code:

```js
console.log(!true);
```

We are flipping the condition. So `true` is obviously true, but `!true` is equal to `false`, since it's been flipped.

The `!` is called **bang** or the **not operator**, and you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)

```js
const string = 'hello world'

// does it include 'hello'?
console.log(string.includes('hello')) // true! it does include 'hello'

// does it NOT include 'hello'?
console.log(!string.includes('hello')) // false. it does include 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exclamation point is more of a javascript thing here. Looking at your code snippet it means it negates the `.includes` result. If it's true, it will be reversed to false and vice versa.

Comment: Not just javascript. Java, C, C++, C# also uses ! to negate a boolean, among others.